# RoutingError when using jQuery UI tabs with ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm getting `ActionController::RoutingError in Profiles#show` when I click a link to render a layout as part of my implementation of jQuery UI tabs. Here's my `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Messages", :controller => 'profiles', :action => 'profile_messages', :remote => true %>
```

**My ProfilesController:**

```
def profile_messages
  @messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

**My `profile_messages` erb layout:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
<% for message in @user.messages %>
  <div class="message-1">
  </div>
<% end %>
</div><!-- end messages -->
```

**Routes.rb:**

```
resources :messages do
  get "messages/profile" => :profile_messages
  resources :responses
end
```

What I want to happen is: when you click the link created by my `link_to`, the layout in `profile_messages.html.erb` shows and loads the messages in that specific layout. What's going on here?

**UPDATE:** Adding the new line in `Routes.rb` gives me a new route:

```
message_messages_profile GET    /messages/:message_id/messages/profile(.:format)  {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"messages"}
```

So I tried this in my Profiles show.html.erb I put:

```
<li><%= link_to "Messages", message_messages_profile_path, :remote => true %></li>
```

This gives me a `RoutingError in Profiles#show` -- `No route matches {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"messages"}`. Even when I add the following into my `MessagesController`:

```
def profile_messages
  @message = @user.messages.find(params[:user_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the combined efforts of folks here on SO I was able to get this to work. Check out these questions for more code:

[Exclude application layout in Rails 3 div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697317/exclude-application-layout-in-rails-3-div)

[Rails 3 jQuery UI Tabs issue loading with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693012/rails-3-jquery-ui-tabs-issue-loading-with-ajax/7698207#comment9363399_7698207)

Answer (score 1):

```
get "messages/profile" => "messages#profile_messages", :as => profile_messages
resource :messages do
  resource :responses
end
```

You don't have a route for that controller action. Rails doesn't map ":controller/:action/:id" by default any more. You can also just enable that route if you want. You could be able to reference this via `profile_messages_path`.

It's assuming 'show' is actually an id for messages here I think. The default routes for a resource are listed here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions. Make sure you list your routes first!

Comment: Is it `resource :messages` or `resources :messages`? I tried both and still get `RoutingError in Profiles#Show` -- `No route matches {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"profiles", :remote=>true}`. Going to localhost3000/messages/profile gives `RecordNotFound in MessagesController#Show` -- `Couldn't find Message with ID=profile`

Comment: So whenever it gives you `Couldn't find Message with ID=profile`, that means you're not hitting the right route. Maybe if you moved the `get` before the resource block. Remember, if you read the `rake routes`, the order it sees stuff is what it goes through. The first match and it's done. Updated my answer a bit. Hopefully this gets you closer.

Answer (score 1):

```
resource :messages do
  collection do
    get :profile_messages
  end
end
```

in your view

```
<li><%= link_to "Messages", "/messages/profile_messages", :remote => true %></li>
```

Comment: I think I see the problem. When I use that and run it, nothing shows. I get an error in firebug: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -- profile_messages`